# CSV writing Ruby Encoding Error

Tags: ruby, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to write a UTF-8 character in a CSV file with csv library of Ruby. And I have got an error:

> csv ruby write problem ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

```
#create csv file
CSV.open(CSV_file,"wb",) do |csv|
  csv << First_line
  rows.each do  |r|
    csv << r.generate_array
  end
end
```

That's the code where UTF-8 conflicts with ASCII-8BIT.

Example text that fails:

> demás

Comment: ruby 2.3.4p301 (2017-03-30 revision 58214) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
Ubuntu 16.04
uname -r 4.10.0-28-generic

Comment: I want to write UTF-8 into a the file.

Comment: r is a class called CSV_row that I have create. They are objects generated in the same script. Taking data from others files, and generating a object with text information that will be inserted to the CSV.

Comment: If you write utf-8, why not use `CSV.open(CSV_file,"w:utf-8"`? YOur example can't be used to show details. E.g. what is `rows` in your code?

Comment: Please add example text

Comment: @knut, that's code does keep the same fail. The rows is a Array of objects of the class CSV_row. CSV_row store strings from other files. And unify everything and then right with special characters like, á or ñ. And then take the fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of CSV writing and reading with UTF-8:

```
fn="/tmp/f.csv"

require "csv"
d1=DATA.read.split(/\n/).map {|e| e.split}
CSV.open(fn, "w:utf-8") do |row|
   d1.each { |dr| row << dr }
end

d2=[]
CSV.foreach(fn) do |row|
  d2 << row
end

puts d1==d2
# true

__END__
privé face à face à un tête-à-tête
Face to face with one-on-one
demás
```

Without a more detailed example from you, I cannot help further.

Comment: the problem was that I read before a file, and I didn't force the read enconde to utf-8. So in the objects I had the information in other encoding. And it was the problem. When you need to write uft-8 ensure to read. `File.open(path,'r:utf-8'){|file| file.read}` Thanks!

Comment: If you do not specify utf-8 when you open a file for writing, its encoding will depend on the encoding of the source strings written. It may be that you are mixing strings with different types of encodings into a single array?

Comment: Yes, I had strings with differents encodings. Because one of the attributes of the objects was a attribute that store information read from a file. When I read that file, I did not specify the enconding reading. So when I specify read like utf-8. Every string of the object had the same encoding.